# Boost::asio return std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, boost-asio, bad-alloc

I tried to run my basic server on 3 different computer (2 on windows and 1 linux) and only my computer fail to run correctly the server. After one or two request, boost asio throw a std::bad_alloc. I checked with Valgrind: no leaks. Linux run my code perfectly as my second computer but mine fail every time. I can't figure out what's in my computer that make the server crash. I tried to disable the antivirus: doesn't work. I made a firewall exception. The codeblock's debugger send me this :

```
 #0 004F7980    __cxa_throw () (??:??)
 #1 004F749E    operator new(unsigned int) () (??:??)
 #2 005CACB8    typeinfo for std::time_put<wchar_t, std::ostreambuf_iterator<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> > > () (??:??)
 #3 004F55F0    std::bad_alloc::what() const () (??:??)
 #4 0AF17F94    ?? () (??:??)
 #5 D0D0D0D0    ?? () (??:??)
```

###The header###

```
 #ifndef MSSID_SERVER_CORE_H_INCLUDED
 #define MSSID_SERVER_CORE_H_INCLUDED
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <memory>
 #include <utility>
 #include <boost/bind.hpp>
 #include <boost/asio.hpp>
 #include "XML/pugixml.hpp"
 #include "XML/pugiconfig.hpp"
 #include "Network/RQUtils.h"
 #include <boost/asio.hpp>
 using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
 using namespace pugi;
 int startServer();
 class MSSID_Session
 : public std::enable_shared_from_this<MSSID_Session>
 {
 public:
 MSSID_Session(tcp::socket socket)
 : socket_(std::move(socket)){};
 ~MSSID_Session();
 void start();
 private:
 void start_routine();
 void greetingsHandle_write(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length);
 void greetingsHandle_read(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length);
 void requestHandle_write(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length);
 void requestHandle_read(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length);
 void headerHandle_write(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length);
 void headerHandle_read(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length);
 void setError(boost::system::error_code ec);
 boost::asio::streambuf sb;
 int err;
 string errmsg;
 char data_[5];
 tcp::socket socket_;
 bool grtd;
 int errc;
 };

 class MSSID_Server
 {
 public:
 MSSID_Server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
 : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
  socket_(io_service)
 {
 start_accept();
 }

 private:
 void start_accept();
 tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
 tcp::socket socket_;
 };
 #endif // MSSID_SERVER_CORE_H_INCLUDED
```

###The source###

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <memory>
 #include <utility>
 #include <boost/bind.hpp>
 #include <boost/asio.hpp>
 #include "MSSID_Server_Core.h"
 #include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
 using boost::asio::ip::tcp;


  MSSID_Session::~MSSID_Session()
  {
  std::cout << "Session ended !" << std::endl;
  }
  void MSSID_Session::start()
  {
  grtd = false;
  std::cout << "Session started !" << std::endl;
  start_routine();
  }
  void MSSID_Session::start_routine()
  {
  auto self(shared_from_this());
  socket_.async_read_some(sb.prepare(5),    boost::bind(&MSSID_Session::greetingsHandle_read,self,boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
  void MSSID_Session::greetingsHandle_read(boost::system::error_code er, size_t len)
  {
  if(er)
    this->setError(er);
  auto self(shared_from_this());
  if(len!=5)
  {
    err = -2;
    errmsg = "[ERROR] Incorrect greetings, aborting socket";
    socket_.close();
  } else
  {
    sb.commit(5);
    string greetings(boost::asio::buffers_begin(sb.data()), boost::asio::buffers_begin(sb.data()) + 5);
    if(strcmp(greetings.c_str(),"MSSID")==0)
    {

        socket_.async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer("MSSID",5), boost::bind(&MSSID_Session::greetingsHandle_write,self,boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    }
    cout << "Greetings read : Done" << endl;
    }
    void MSSID_Session::greetingsHandle_write(boost::system::error_code er, size_t len)
    {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    if(er)
    this->setError(er);
    if(len!=5)
    {
    err = -3;
    errmsg = "[ERROR] Can't send greeting : " + er.message();
    socket_.close();
    }
    boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_,sb,"</MSSID>",boost::bind(&MSSID_Session::headerHandle_read,self,boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
   cout << "C'est bon " << endl;
   }
   void MSSID_Session::headerHandle_read(boost::system::error_code er, size_t len)
   {
   if(er)
    this->setError(er);
   sb.commit(len);
   string header(boost::asio::buffers_begin(sb.data()), boost::asio::buffers_begin(sb.data()) + sb.size());

   }
   void MSSID_Server::start_accept()
   {
   acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
                       [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
    if (!ec)
    {
        std::make_shared<MSSID_Session>(std::move(socket_))->start();
    }
    start_accept();
    });
    }
    int startServer()
    {
    try
    {

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::thread_group threadpool;
    MSSID_Server s(io_service, 5553);
    
    io_service.run();
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
}

return 0;
}
void MSSID_Session::setError(boost::system::error_code ec)
{
err = ec.value();
errmsg = ec.message();
}
```

Comment: Check if your PC runs out of RAM.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I got 32 Go, and I'm really fine with that

Comment: Run it under the debugger and set the debugger to trap the exception being thrown, then check how much memory is being asked for.

Comment: @TimoGeusch It's about 33Mo

Comment: Have you checked if you're running into any process limits? 33MB is a lot to ask for in a single chunk, the allocator might not be able to satisfy that if you're seeing some memory fragmentation and hitting process limits.

Comment: @TimoGeusch 33Mo is when the program crashes, but each request is not that much. And don't think that I have some process limits.

Comment: @TheBluff, std::bad_alloc is being thrown whenever the runtime library's allocator can't satisfy a single allocation request. That's why I suggested to check how much memory is being requested at the point that the std::bad_alloc is being thrown. Overall memory consumption doesn't usually have anything to do with it, IME it's more often a wrong parameter being passed to the allocator that causes issues like this.